# internal anchor in ScrewTurn wiki

Tags: wiki, screwturn

I'm using ScrewTurn wiki and I can't get internal (same-page) linking to work.  The documentation is very unclear on this point, only providing 1 example which makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the syntax of anchor links.  The first line is the line that creates your link to an anchor on the page, the second line is the line that creates the actual anchor.  Is this how you are doing it?

```
[#MyAnchorLink|This Is the Link Text to My Anchor]

[anchor|#MyAnchorLink]This is the beginning of my target anchor
```